# How can I see the storage size of a document in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

How can I see the storage size of a document in CosmosDB?

I am trying some different formats for storing data as effective as possible, but I do not know how to see the storage size so I can compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is reported in the [Query Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics). Look for `Retrieved Document Size`.

You can see it in Data Explorer as the `Query Stats` tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution to the accepted answer. It is possible to get query execution metrics by code. That includes document size. More information can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics#query-execution-metrics

Below is a code example from the above link that shows how to get the metrics data:

```
IDocumentQuery<dynamic> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName), 
"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.city = 'Seattle'", 
new FeedOptions 
{ 
    PopulateQueryMetrics = true, 
}).AsDocumentQuery();

FeedResponse<dynamic> result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync();

// Returns metrics by partition key range Id
IReadOnlyDictionary<string, QueryMetrics> metrics = result.QueryMetrics;
```

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to show actual code. Otherwise this is just a link to documentation, and link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: And yes, I realize you're answering your own question. Still... it really needs to be a specific answer, not just a link to docs.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for the suggestion, I have now included a code example.